# NumPy / Sklearn: Get Highest in Row Subject to Constraint

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a 2d NumPy array, `scores` where the columns represent classes and the rows represent samples.  The `i`th row and `j`th column represent the score for sample `i` and class `j`.

I want to create another 2d NumPy array where there's a 1 at `scores[i, j]` if the score for that class exceeds the threshold required for 70% precision for that class.  If there are ties, we break them by taking the highest score.  There should be a single 1 entry per row in my output 2d NumPy array.

I can do this by going through each column (class) and calculating the threshold needed to give me 70% precision, using `sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve`.  Then I can go through each row like this:

```
new_matrix = np.zeros(scores.shape)        
for i, row in enumerate(scores):
    max_score = 0
    max_index = -1
    for i, score in enumerate(row):
        if score > get_threshold(i) and score > max_score:
            max_score = score
            max_index = i
    if max_index != -1:
        new_matrix[i][max_index] = 1
```

1) Is there a way I can vectorize this instead of using for-loops?

2) Is there library code that does the above?  I've poked through the `sklearn` docs, but closest I've found is `precision_recall_curve` which works per-class, not per 2-d NumPy Array.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, the following code should work. But I'm not sure if there were better ways, just FYI

```
s = scores.copy()
# mask scores which don't meet the thresholds, assuming original scores are non-negative
s[s <= thresholds] = -1

new_matrix = np.zeros(scores.shape)
new_matrix[np.arange(scores.shape[0]), s.argmax(axis=1)] = 1
new_matrix[s == -1] = 0
```

`thresholds` above is something like `np.array([get_threshold(i) for i in range(scores.shape[1])])`